# What does [:] mean?

Tags: python, arrays, syntax, slice

I'm analyzing some Python code and I don't know what

```
pop = population[:]
```

means. Is it something like array lists in Java or like a bi-dimensional array?

Comment: Related, clearing a list is only possible by doing del pop[:] or pop[:] = [], not pop.clear() .. (as you do with dicts).

Comment: Good SO discussion of Python slice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: @Macke: Note: As of Python 3.3, `list`s do provide `clear` and `copy` methods, equivalent to doing `del mylist[:]` or `mylist[:]` respectively. They're not required on mutable sequences in general, so if you might receive an arbitrary mutable sequence, you'd want to stick to slice based operations, but the named methods are at least available on `list`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, 9 years later. :-)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

It is an example of slice notation, and what it does depends on the type of `population`.  If `population` is a list, this line will create a [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy) of the list.  For an object of type `tuple` or a `str`, it will do nothing (the line will do the same without `[:]`), and for a (say) NumPy array, it will create a new view to the same data.

Comment: Just in case: the slice returns a shallow copy.

Comment: Using `l.copy()` for a list may be more readable than `l[:]`, unless 4 characters longer.

Comment: @ilius: Maybe `l.copy()` is more readable, but it won't work.

Comment: `list(l)` always works, is more readable, and is guaranteed to return a copy even with something like `numpy.array`

Comment: @SvenMarnach: stay tuned for 3.3, where `list.copy` has been added

Comment: @Eli: Yes, alongside `list.clear()`.  It will take some time, though, until this will lead to a significant reduction of this kind of questions on SO. :)

Comment: Since I couldn't find this anywhere on line, the way to express that colon programmatically is `slice(None)`.  So the above is equivalent to `x = slice(None)` then `pop = population(x)`.  Very useful for multidimensional arrays.  Instead of `A[:,0,:]` you can determined from which dimension to get a slice programmatically.  `x = deque(chain((0,), repeat(slice(None), dim-1))` then `A[x.rotate(position)]`

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk: I assume you are talking about NumPy arrays here.  Rather than using `A[deque(chain((k,), repeat(slice(None), len(A.shape) - 1)).rotate(axis)]`, I'd almost always prefer `numpy.rollaxis(A, axis, 0)[k]`.  In general, I've rarely come across a use case where you would need to directly create `slice()` objects.  If you need them anyway, NumPy provides the [`s_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html#numpy.s_) helper as an alternative way to create them.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, thanks, I did not know about rollaxis.

Comment: @EthanFurman: the slice does not automatically convert to list. For example `(1,2,3)[:]` will yield the tuple `(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 37):

It might also help to know that a list slice in general makes a copy of part of the list. E.g. `population[2:4]` will return a list containing population[2] and population[3] (slicing is right-exclusive). Leaving away the left and right index, as in `population[:]` they default to 0 and length(population) respectively, thereby selecting the entire list. Hence this is a common idiom to make a copy of a list.

Answer (score 18):

well... this really depends on the context.  Ultimately, it passes a [`slice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) object (`slice(None,None,None)`) to one of the following methods:  [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) or [`__delitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__).  (Actually, if the object has a [`__getslice__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#additional-methods-for-emulation-of-sequence-types), that will be used instead of `__getitem__`, but that is now deprecated and shouldn't be used).

Objects can do what they want with the slice.

In the context of:

```
x = obj[:]
```

This will call `obj.__getitem__` with the slice object passed in.  In fact, this is completely equivalent to:

```
x = obj[slice(None,None,None)]
```

(although the former is probably more efficient because it doesn't have to look up the `slice` constructor -- It's all done in bytecode).

For most objects, this is a way to create a shallow copy of a portion of the sequence.

Next:

```
x[:] = obj
```

Is a way to set the items (it calls `__setitem__`) based on `obj`.

and, I think you can probably guess what:

```
del x[:]
```

calls ;-).

You can also pass different slices:

```
x[1:4]
```

constructs `slice(1,4,None)`

```
x[::-1]
```

constructs `slice(None,None,-1)` and so forth.  Further reading:  [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)

Answer (score 12):

It is a [slice](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) from the beginning of the sequence to the end, usually producing a shallow copy.

(Well, it's [more than that](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), but you don't need to care yet.)

Answer (score 8):

[:]
used for limiter or slicing in array , hash
eg:

[1:5] for displaying values between 1 inclusive and 5 exclusive i.e 1-4
[start:end]

basically used in array for slicing , understand bracket accept variable that mean value or key to display, and " : "  is used to limit or slice the entire array into packets .

Comment: No reason to bump such an old question which already has 5 similar answers and even an accepted one... Besides, `a[1:5]` returns elements 1-4, not 2-4.

Comment: @SkamahOne Oh I don't know. Maybe not in this case but there are times where it can be of value to raise dead questions. Different insight, different wording etc. In this case you corrected the answer and they hopefully learnt something too.

Answer (score 7):

It creates a copy of the list, versus just assigning a new name for the already existing list.