# ValueError: matrices are not aligned for copy error and x[:]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dot-product

I got the ValueError as given below.

ValueError: matrices are not aligned for copy error

It was traced to the following line (I did not write this code, I am trying to use it):

```
x1[:] =  _dotproduct(x1, u)
```

The dot product is like numpy dot product, it works FINE, `printing _dotproduct(x1, u)` give a valid answer. It is `x1[:]` that is not working.

What does `[:]` mean? I have never seen that.

Also how can I solve the error of alignment?

**Edit:**
I have now traced the error to `x1[:]`, so instead of this can I do the following:

```
hh=len(x1)
```

`x1[0:hh]=_dotproduct(x1, u)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does \[:\] in Python mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167238/what-does-in-python-mean)

Comment: `[:]` is a shallow copy notation for lists. https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Thank you, I did not come across it.

Comment: why is it giving a problem? I cam across this online:http://starship.python.net/pipermail/mmtk/2008/001447.html

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since it's on the left side of the `=` sign, it's a slice assignment. The object `x1` remains the same object, but all its contents are replaced with the sequence on the right. Without the `[:]`, `x1` would be assigned to a totally different object.

Using a slice assignment means that if there are other references to the same variable in your program, all of these will see the new contents. For example, the caller of a function passes in a container and the function replaces its contents. This wouldn't be possible without the slice assignment.

Comment: Thank you but it is the left side  x1[:] that is giving rise to the alignment error. As noted in my comment, this gives a clue but not a solution. http://starship.python.net/pipermail/mmtk/2008/001447.html

Comment: Sorry, I thought your actual question was "What does [:] mean?"

Comment: sorry, I am terrible at explaining things and English is not my strong point. So terribly sorry for the confusion. It was a two part question now I edit it.