# What does colon at assignment for list[:] = [...] do in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came accross the following code:

```
# O(n) space       
def rotate(self, nums, k):
    deque = collections.deque(nums)
    k %= len(nums)
    for _ in xrange(k):
        deque.appendleft(deque.pop())
    nums[:] = list(deque) # <- Code in question
```

What does `nums[:] =` do that `nums =` does not? For that matter, what does `nums[:]` do that `nums` does not?

Comment: Asked and answered I believe. [What does \[:\] in Python mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167238/what-does-in-python-mean)

Comment: @CollinD Didn't see that question, thanks. But still doesn't answer the assignment question

Comment: I had voted to reopen because I didn't think the linked duplicate explained slice assignment. I must have opened the wrong link, because it definitely does explain slice assignment.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This syntax is a slice assignment.  A slice of `[:]` means the entire list.  The difference between `nums[:] =` and `nums =` is that the latter doesn't replace elements in the original list. This is observable when there are two references to the list

```
>>> original = [1, 2, 3]
>>> other = original
>>> original[:] = [0, 0] # changes the contents of the list that both
                         # original and other refer to 
>>> other # see below, now you can see the change through other
[0, 0]
```

To see the difference just remove the `[:]` from the assignment above.

```
>>> original = [1, 2, 3]
>>> other = original
>>> original = [0, 0] # original now refers to a different list than other
>>> other # other remains the same
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

Note: vincent thorpe's comments below are either incorrect or irrelevant to the question. This is not a matter of value vs reference semantics, nor whether you apply the operator to an lvalue or rvalue.

Comment: Simply say, (list[:] = ...) is value type but (list = ...) is reference type

Comment: @Brady Huang that doesn't describe this accurately

Comment: you are saying that slice notation `list[:]` means the reference, while the `list` means the copy? then why in  `for in list:` if you pass the `list` itself and you insert some element inside the loop, this loop will never end because since its incrementing its length it will be forever. it means if yo'u pass `list` without[:] you are passing the reference. that's contradictory huh

Comment: the [:] operator if you put Lvalue or Rvalue it means different

Comment: @vincentthorpe `lst[:]` not followed by an `=` calls `__getitem__`, while `lst[:] = ` calls `__setitem__`, so `[]` and `[]=` are best thought of as two different operators

Comment: @Ryan Haining yes l spend serveral hours to find out this.

Answer (score 14):

`nums = foo` rebinds the name `nums` to refer to the same object that `foo` refers to.

`nums[:] = foo` invokes slice assignment on the object that `nums` refers to, thus making the contents of the original object a copy of the contents of `foo`.

Try this:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [3,4,5]
>>> c = a
>>> c = b
>>> print(a)
[1, 2]
>>> c = a
>>> c[:] = b
>>> print(a)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Better answer in my opinion

Comment: "***...rebinds...***" indeed, +1

Comment: Best answer indeed. The example is a little weird though, since you never print "c".