# Python list assignment with colon in brackets [:]

Tags: python, list, dictionary, variable-assignment, python-3.5

I am working with python 3.5 lists on a very performance dependent application.

After searching for [object removal in a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235631/2202071) I wondered about the colon `[:]` in that solution. I am aware that it creates a copy (theoretically), but in this example see no purpose for it.

Does it maybe save memory? Or does it have to do with shallow/deep copies? Will python behave differently for the cases of an existing `mylist = ...` versus `mylist[:] = ...`?

I've found some similar questions but none with how python behaves given such a assignment.

Comment: @vaultah Thanks for bringing the [middle duplicate with two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32448477/2202071) to my attention, as it mostly covers my question. I've seen and read the other two, which don't address the main point.