# Replacing a value through three list's elements in Python

Tags: python, list, element

```
A = ['d','a','c','a','a','d','a','d','c','e']
B = ['a','d','c','e']
C = ['z','x', 'y','k']
```

As you can see from above, I have three lists. List A is a random mix of characters, and B is a reordering of elements in the A list by frequency without duplicating them. The list C is the values I want to replace. I would like to check if the values in list B are in A and change the values in list A to those in list C. If there is a value 'B[0]' in list A, I would like to change all 'B[0]' values in list A change to C[0]. The rest of the elements also want to do so.

What I want:

```
A=['x','z','y','z','z','x','z','x','y','k']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to create a dictionary with keys `B` to values `C` and use that dictionary to replace the values in `A`.

```py
A = ['d','a','c','a','a','d','a','d','c','e']
B = ['a','d','c','e']
C = ['z','x', 'y','k']

char_dict = dict(zip(B, C))
for i, char in enumerate(A):
    A[i] = char_dict[char]
```

This can also be done using list comprehension

```py
char_dict = dict(zip(B, C))
A = [char_dict[char] for char in A]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a translation dict [out of B and C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/209840/4518341) and use a list comprehension.

```
>>> d = dict(zip(B, C))
>>> [d[x] for x in A]
['x', 'z', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'k']
```

If some values in `A` may not be in `B`, you could replace `d[x]` with something like `d.get(x, x)`.

And if you need to overwrite the values of `A`, use [slice assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32448477/4518341):

```
A[:] = [d[x] for x in A]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary that maps characters to be replaced with their replacement and substitute the characters in a list comprehension:

```
A = ['d','a','c','a','a','d','a','d','c','e']
B = ['a','d','c','e']
C = ['z','x', 'y','k']

subs = dict(zip(B, C))
A = [subs[c] for c in A]

>>> A
['x', 'z', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'x', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'k']
```

We can assume that `subs[c]` will always succeed because `B` is derived from `A` and therefore all items in `B` must also be present in `A`.

If that were not the case then you could use `dict.get()` instead:

```
A = [subs.get(c, c) for c in A]
```